# Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I'm working through a MEAN Stack book called "MEAN Web Development". It's been a great book so far, but  I'm currently stuck. I've downloaded all the code they provide so I can double check my work and it seems all my code is correct. I've searched for similar errors and tried to implement versions of those errors, but nothing has worked yet. According to the error these are the files that are producing the error.

Another note, when I remove the code for the `list` function. Everything works fine with just the `create` function. But, as soon as I add in the `list` function again it breaks and gives me the error that Return.get() needs a callback. but got an undefined object.

users.server.controller

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
var user = new User(req.body);

user.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(user);
    }
});
};


exports.list = function(req, res, next) {
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(users);
    }
});
};
```

users.server.routes

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.route('/users')
    .post(users.create)
    .get(users.list);
};
```

express.js

```
var config = require('./config'),
express = require('express'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
compress = require('compression'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
session = require('express-session');


module.exports = function() {
var app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(compress());
}
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret
}));

app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);

app.use(express.static('./public'));

return app;
}
```

server.js

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var mongoose = require('./config/mongoose'),
    express = require('./config/express');

var db = mongoose();
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000/');
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: `users.create` and `users.list` inside `users.server.routes` are undefined.

Comment: @Randy When I get rid of the `users.list` code from both the `users.server.routes` file and the `users.server.controller` file. The code works with the `users.create` code. But as soon as I add the `users.list` code back in, I get the error.

Comment: You're probably right. I glanced over it real quick.

Comment: And I also realized that they are undefined. I don't know WHY it is though. I'm not sure what else to try and change to make the error go away. I've tried quite a few things already from previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through the same book and got this same error.

It seems the app is looking for the exports.signout function that is never shown that should be written in app/controllers/users.server.controller.js

I just wrote it like this:

```
exports.signout = function(req, res, nest) {
};
```

And then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Put your

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
```

inside your module.exports method, like this:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

  app.route('/users')
    .post(users.create)
    .get(users.list);
};
```