# Issue passing data to child routes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im new to Node.js and keep getting the `Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]` error

and Ive checked out the following question and either dont understand or im still doing something wrong

[Express routes: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124909/express-routes-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-object)

[.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616074/get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined)

[Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335365/error-route-get-requires-callback-functions-but-got-a-object-undefined)

[Node Route.get() requires callback function but got a [object undefined]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26478153/node-route-get-requires-callback-function-but-got-a-object-undefined)

my file structure is

```
server.js
routes/api/geolocations.js
routes/api/geolocations/regions.js
routes/api/geolocations/destination.js
```

**ROOT: server.js**

```
var geolocation = require('./routes/api/geolocation')(app);
app.get('/geolocation/', geolocation.delegate);
```

then I pass my data to `routes/api/geolocations.js` by using

```
geolocation.delegate(unparsedData);
```

from there I parse the data and send it down it's appropriate child routes.

---

**PARENT: geolocations.js** in my `routes/api/geolocations.js`

```
   var destination = require('./geolocations/destination');
   var region = require('./geolocations/region');

   module.exports = function(app) {
        return {

      app.get('./geolocation/region', region.delegate);
      app.get('./geolocation/destination', destination.delegate);


            delegate: function(unparsedData, req, res) {


          var data =[setup package for child states using unparsedData]


         //HERE Id like to pass the new `data` to region or destination using the following
         region.delegate(data);
         //OR
         destination.delegate(data);
```

**CHILDREN: region.js / destination.js** in `routes/api/geolocations/regions.js` or `routes/api/geolocations/destination.js`

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    return {
        delegate: function(data, req, res) {

        ...do stuff
   }
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I guess I dont know where to set up my routes, in `server.js` or if i can in `geoloaction.js`, does it matter, do need to do something like this in server.js?

```
var regions = require('./routes/api/geolocation/regions')([pass stuff here]);
geolocation.get('./routes/api/geolocation/regions', regions.delegate);
```

Comment: My first question is why do you try to make this structure so complicated.  Start with a much simpler structure, then slowly break things into other files one piece at a time so you can see exactly what is and isn't working.  Also, geolocations.js looks like illegal code.  You have `app.get()` calls in the middle of an object definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use express.js easy setup and run.

Simply download IntelliJ IDEA, find free version, then install. Then run the application and goto File->Setting->Plugin and search for NodeJS then install. Followed to this you need to Enable it. To do this goto File->Setting->Language & Frameworks->**open arrow**-> JavaScript**open arrow**->Libraries->Enable Node.js Core.

File Structure
routes/api/geolocations.js
routes/api/geolocations/regions.js
routes/api/geolocations/destination.js

You can have a look at the below code that might help you get started.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var regions = require('../api/geolocations/regions');
var destination = require('../api/geolocations/destination');
//------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* geolocation.js */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var region_ext = regions.to_export;
    var destin_ext = destination.to_export;

    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Geolocation',
        region: region_ext,
        destination:destin_ext
    });
});
module.exports = router;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* region.js */
var to_export = function () {
    return 'this is from regions';
}
module.exports.to_export = to_export();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------



//------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* destination.js */
var to_export = function () {
    return 'this is from destination';
}
module.exports.to_export = to_export();
//------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//In app.js, just change 
var routes = require('./routes/api/geolocations');
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

jfriend00 is right, You got a little mess there. Maybe you should consider make use of next(), since if you use it the other middlewares will have a chance of manipulating the request.

Comment: ok thanks for the tips, I'll look into changing my structure a little bit